# cannot create a new user on mysql 5.1.73

Tags: mysql

This does not seem to work

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR juser201411@localhost= PASSWORD(".6,y:C2a");

ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

After that I tried manually adding from mysql.user

```
mysql> update mysql.user set password=('.6,y:C2a') where User='juser201411' and Host='localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select User from mysql.user;+------+
| User |
+------+
| root |
| root |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

centos 6.5 x64

Comment: there are no `juser201411` user in your user table, so you can not do anything with that. First you need to create the user: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

Comment: thanks, it seemed this is the right way `CREATE USER 'juser201411'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ".6,y:C2a";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `CREATE USER` syntax. For more information see [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

```
CREATE USER 'juser201411'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '.6,y:C2a';
```

Comment: it seemed that gave `ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'juser201411@localhost' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)`. So I tried `CREATE USER 'juser201411'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD(".6,y:C2a");` but that gave `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(".6,y:C2a")' at line 1`

Comment: @grepmaster I have changed my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had put the line into a txt editor to fill it out and some of my single quotes had gotten converted to smart quotes...hard to see, but obvious once you do(!)